# Can you leave the UK and return on a Tier 2 visa?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I have a 5-year valid UK residence permit (ICT Tier 2 Visa) and have lived in the country for 15 months. I had to go back home (India) for a couple of months due to personal reasons. Now, I need to get back in for a 2-week meeting (still working for the same company) and get back home. Is this allowed as part of the existing visa, or should I have to apply for a separate business visa/visitor visa?

Comment: [Tier 2 (Intra-company Transfer) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-intracompany-transfer-worker-visa) lists "travel abroad and return to the UK" as one of the things you can do on the visa.

Comment: How many months have you been absent from the UK?

Answer (score 1):

[Tier 2 (Intra-company Transfer) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-intracompany-transfer-worker-visa) lists the following things as allowed on a Tier 2 visa:

> - work for your sponsor in the job described in your certificate of sponsorship
> - do a second job in the same profession and at the same level as your main job for up to 20 hours per week
> - do voluntary work
> - study as long as it doesn’t interfere with the job you’re sponsored for
> - **travel abroad and return to the UK**
> - bring family members with you

So the answer is **yes**, what you're proposing is allowed.

Comment: How long we can stay outside? May be more than a year?